# Is it possible to give all data fields the same rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Do you have to `.validate` all data fields individually, or can you make rules cascade over some and not others?

because currently , only 1 field would do what i want in my rules and the other field will ignore the validate.

example:

```json
    {
      "rules": {
        "users": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
           "$uid": {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
    
            "kills": {
                                     //THIS ONE GETS IGNORED
              ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == data.val() +1",
            },
              
            "deaths": {
                                     //THIS ONE WORKS.
              ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == data.val() +1",

            "score": {
              ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == data.val() +100",
             }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [wildcard cpture variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables) to create a rule that applies to all children, except the ones for which you have a named rule.

If your existing rules have the same validation for `kills` and `deaths`, you could shorten them to this and get the same result:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",

                "$other": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == data.val() +1",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that means you'd lose the dedicated validation of `deaths/score`, as you can't override a single named child for a wildcard.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir. this was a lot of help. have an awesome day further.